# Java NumberFormat ignoring comma in US locale ?

Tags: java, localization, locale, number-formatting

I don't understand something in the NumberFormat, in US locale it is suppose to treat comma (",") as a group separator - for thousands.

Why does it ignore commas in incorrect places for this locale ?

```
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); 
System.out.println(format.parse("5,500").longValue()); //5500
System.out.println(format.parse("550,0").longValue()); //5500
System.out.println(format.parse("5500,").longValue()); //5500
```

any other ideas how to parse String to Long according to locale (asumming that input of ","
in incorrect places for the locale should fail) ?

Comment: What do you mean when you say *incorrect place* ? All the statements on your example are valid.

Comment: Try `format.setGroupingUsed(true)`. Does it make a difference?

Comment: @Puce: It defaults to `true` for `Locale.US`.

Comment: @Puce, this is not related. With parser but with also like setGroupingSize(int). The groping separator is just not part of format validation even if you set pattern "#,#00.0#" i will accept all above values.

Comment: Where do you read that "in US locale it is suppose to treat comma (",") as a group separator - for thousands"

Answer (score 0):

The comma is a placeholder for the grouping separator, and the period is a placeholder for the decimal separator.

```
NumberFormat format = DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.US); 
System.out.println(format.parse("5.500").longValue()); //5
System.out.println(format.parse("55.00").longValue()); //55
System.out.println(format.parse("550.0").longValue()); //550
```

The comma is ignored as is from of presentation. The contract that is used for thousands is common but it does not have any representation during parsing. That is why it is called *grouping separator* not *thousands separator*. You could have something like `5,5.0,0,` and it will be still valid.

How the digit are grouped may differ, sometimes it is by 3 digit some time by 2 or combined.

Logically speaking if it is only separator that is used for simplify the read by humans. His position do not change the value of presented number there fore can be omitted.

---

The analysis of class `java.text.DecimalFormat` implemented by Oracle shows that the grouping characters are ignored.

```
1526  // Ignore grouping characters, if we are using them, but
1527  // require that they be followed by a digit.  Otherwise
1528  // we backup and reprocess them.
```

For more visit [Formatting Numeric Print Output](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html)

Comment: He states this in the question, I think he wants the parsing to fail if the comma is in the wrong place.

Comment: He do not want that, he do want to know what is not falling. I have added some comment to that.

Comment: as Keppil said, i wanted this to fail if the grouping is incorrect (depending in the locale) - if its possible at all

Comment: The class `DecimalFormat`, that you are using can not do that. You can use Regex to validate the input.

Comment: "You could have something like 5,5.0,0, and it will be still valid."  True, but in Java 8, at least, you can't do something like that with digits other than 0.  So "5,5.0,1" is interpreted as "55.0" not "55.01", and more importantly "0.123,456" is treated as "0.123".  You can have as many commas as you want on the left, but on the right, parsing stops when it hits the first comma.

Answer (score 0):

As javadev mentions, the parse method just seems to ignore thousand separators. I guess you would have to implement a parse method yourself (using the information of the NumberFormat/DecimalFormat) if you want strict parsing.

Answer (score -1):

As the comma is a the separator for thousands in US Locale, it is ignored when it is wrongly placed.
All of these ouputs will print 5500.

Comment: He states this in the question, I think he wants the parsing to fail if the comma is in the wrong place.